# What inputs should i use to get more precise prediction?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting negative predictive results when I'm running Google big query. My tables structure is like this (simplified):

```
product: id(INT), auction_id(INT), title(STRING), description(STRING),qty(INT), status(as STRING);<br>
product_invoice: id(INT), product_id(INT), sale_price_amount(INT), tax_price_amount(INT);<br>
auction: id(INT), title(STRING), start_date(DATETIME);
```

I use this query to create a model:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `auction.test_dataset.lot_model`
OPTIONS
  (model_type='linear_reg', labels=['single_item_sale_price_amount_before_tax']) 
AS
WITH 
lot_invoice AS (
  SELECT
  *
  FROM `auction.test_dataset.product_invoice` invoice_line
),
final_query AS (
  SELECT
    lot.title as title,
    IFNULL(lot.qty, 0) as qty_sold,
    (
      CAST(IFNULL(lot_invoice.sale_price_amount, 0) AS INT64) + 0
    ) AS single_item_sale_price_amount_before_tax,
    (
      CAST(IFNULL(lot.qty, 0) AS INT64) * CAST(IFNULL(lot_invoice.sale_price_amount, 0) AS INT64)
    ) AS total_sale_price_amount_before_tax
  FROM `auction.test_dataset.product` lot
  LEFT JOIN lot_invoice ON lot_invoice.lot_id = lot.id
  RIGHT JOIN `auction.test_dataset.auction` auction ON auction.id = lot.auction_id
  WHERE
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM auction.start_date) = 2020
  GROUP BY 
    lot.title,
    lot.qty,
    lot_invoice.sale_price_amount,
    lot_invoice.tax_due_amount,
    lot_invoice.premium_due_amount
)
SELECT
  *
FROM final_query
```

But when I'm trying to predict the sale price it produce negative predicted sale price results. Here is the prediction query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
*
FROM
  ml.PREDICT(MODEL `auction.test_dataset.lot_model`,
  (
    WITH 
    lot_description_vectors AS (
      SELECT
        id,
        auction_id,
        title,
        description,
        qty,
        SPLIT(description, ' ') AS words
      FROM `auction.test_dataset.product` lot
      WHERE
        lot.description IS NOT NULL
      AND
        lot.status IN ('sold')
    ),
    lot_title_vectors AS (
      SELECT
        id,
        auction_id,
        title,
        description,
        qty,
        SPLIT(title, ' ') AS words
      FROM `auction.test_dataset.product` lot
      WHERE
        lot.status IN ('sold')
    ),
    recommended_lots AS (
      SELECT
        b.id AS recommended_lot_id,
        b.auction_id as auction_id,
        b.title as title,
        b.qty as qty,
        (
          SELECT
            SUM(IF(a_word = b_word, 1, 0)) / SQRT(COUNT(a_word) * COUNT(b_word))
          FROM
            UNNEST(a.words) AS a_word,
            UNNEST(b.words) AS b_word
        ) AS cosine_similarity
      FROM
        lot_title_vectors a
      CROSS JOIN
        lot_title_vectors b
      WHERE
        a.title LIKE '%Dining table%' -- As an example looking to make a prediction for the product with the title as Dining table 

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        b.id AS recommended_lot_id,
        b.auction_id as auction_id,
        b.title as title,
        b.qty as qty,
        (
            SELECT
                SUM(IF(a_word = b_word, 1, 0)) / SQRT(COUNT(a_word) * COUNT(b_word))
            FROM
                UNNEST(a.words) AS a_word,
                UNNEST(b.words) AS b_word
        ) AS cosine_similarity
      FROM
        lot_description_vectors a
      CROSS JOIN
        lot_description_vectors b
      WHERE
        a.description LIKE '%Dining table%' -- As an example looking to make a prediction for the product with the description containing Dining table words
      ORDER BY
        cosine_similarity DESC
      LIMIT 10
    ),
    lot_invoice AS (
      SELECT
      *
      FROM `auction.test_dataset.product_invoice` invoice_line
    ),
    final_query AS (
      SELECT
        recommended_lots.title as title,
        IFNULL(recommended_lots.qty, 0) as qty_sold,
        (
          CAST(IFNULL(lot_invoice.sale_price_amount, 0) AS INT64) + 0
        ) AS single_item_sale_price_amount_before_tax,
        (
          CAST(IFNULL(recommended_lots.qty, 0) AS INT64) * CAST(IFNULL(lot_invoice.sale_price_amount, 0) AS INT64)
        ) AS total_sale_price_amount_before_tax
      FROM recommended_lots
      LEFT JOIN lot_invoice ON lot_invoice.lot_id = recommended_lots.recommended_lot_id
      LEFT JOIN `auction.test_dataset.auction` auction ON auction.id = recommended_lots.auction_id
      GROUP BY 
        recommended_lots.title,
        recommended_lots.qty,
        lot_invoice.sale_price_amount,
        lot_invoice.tax_due_amount,
        lot_invoice.premium_due_amount
    )
    SELECT
      *
    FROM final_query
  ))
```

Can somebody point me up what I'm doing wrong or how I can improve my model and predictive query to get rid off negative numbers and start get some mean full results?
Thank you for your help.